# Attaching file to PDF via Access VBA using Adobe SDK

Tags: vba, ms-access, adobe

I'm trying to automatically add an attachment to a PDF file through VBA.
From what I can tell it is possible to handle this through FileAttachment annotations.

```
    Dim testAnno As Object
    Dim props As Object
    
    Set testAnno = jso.AddAnnot
    Set props = testAnno.getProps
    props.Type = "FileAttachment"
    
    ' Code to attach file to PDF as attachment ......
    
    testAnno.setProps props
```

I've found the following example in the Adobe documentation so essentially looking for a VBA equivalent to this:

```
var annot = this.addAnnot({
page: 0
type: "FileAttachment",
point: [400,500],
author: "A. C. Robat",
contents: "Call Smith to get help on this paragraph.",
cAttachmentPath: "/d/a.pdf" ,
});
```

Comment: Code to select filepath is one part of question and usually accomplished with FSO dialog - if you want user to select file. The SDK code to then attach located file is another issue. I am not finding anything. Question is too broad.

Comment: Apologies, I'm good on the front of selecting a file. I'm wondering if there's functionality to attach a file from a filepath to a PDF through code. I've dug through the Adobe SDK documentation and have yet to find anything as well.